# Where can i see touch and feel before i order : Talmud bavli Oz Vehadar Safa Brura

Tags: talmud-bavli

I live in Jerusalem (Israel). 
I am to buy a complet set of Talmud bavli Oz Vehadar Safa Brura.
But before i would like to see one for real.

Does any one knows where in Jerusalem i can see touch and feel (pages, color, dimensions, leather, weight etc...) : a bookstore, a kollel, a shule.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried poking around Sefarim stores near Kikar Shabbat?

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/search?client=ms-android-gionee&ei=XDcfWMCTLMrSU4aHkPgL&q=חנות+ספרי+קודש++בירושלים&oq=חנות+ספרי+קודש++בירושלים&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12..0j0i7i30k1.19207.24138.0.25493.7.6.1.0.0.0.892.2476.2-3j1j1j0j1.6.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.7.2506.D0WpUKYJAdM

Comment: Manny's in Geula?

Comment: From the question it sounds like you have decided from whom you will buy the gemoro and you now want to use a different shop or place to inspect it before buying.  It could be unfair to the shopkeeper to do that unless you tell him why you are doing it and he agrees. So a kollel or shul would be a better bet.